# Find value of x on a chord in the circle - which of the statements is true

Tags: circles

[in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiomK.png)
[image]

In the above image, is there a specific theorem that can be used to state which of the four statements must be true for x?

Comment: The part of $\;a\;$ inside the circle must be less that a diameter (which is a *maximal chord* in any circle) as we're told that that line doesn't pass through $\;\mathcal O\;$ ,so...

Comment: Thus, answer (1). Thank you.  Would there be a way of calculating the exact measurement?

Comment: True, hence the answer is (1). I was just asking for my own edification, but I'm assuming the answer is in the negative. Thank you!

Comment: No, there is no way of calculating the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

The chord labeled $a$ is shorter than the diameter which is $4\text{ cm}$.  One segment of this chord is given as $1.5\text{ cm}$, so by difference the remains segment must be ... Uh-oh, gotta run.  Can you finish?